# How do I convert an NSHttpCookie to a System.Net.Cookie in MonoTouch?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I have a MonoTouch iPhone app that does federated sign in via the Azure Access Control Service. The login is done via an embedded UIWebView browser. When the login is done, I want to transfer the cookie into my app. I have access to the

```
NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.Cookies
```

collection, so I can find the cookie. But in order to call the back end services, I need to have a

```
System.Net.Cookie
```

that I can put into a CookieContainer to send to the service.

How do I convert between the two... is this the only way?

```
NSHttpCookie cookie = NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.Cookies[0];
System.Net.Cookie newCookie = new System.Net.Cookie()
    {
        Name = cookie.Name,
        Value = cookie.Value,
        Version = (int) cookie.Version,
        Expires = cookie.ExpiresDate,
        Domain = cookie.Domain,
        Path = cookie.Path,
        Port = cookie.PortList[0].ToString(), // is this correct??
        Secure = cookie.IsSecure,
        HttpOnly = cookie.IsHttpOnly
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is how you could convert.  Perhaps you should just make an extension method on NSHttpCookie?  Then you could call something like:

```
var c = cookie.ToCLRCookie ();
```