# How do I put a cookie into Shared Storage on an iPhone App?

Tags: c#, iphone, cookies, httpwebrequest, xamarin.ios

I am using Monotouch to develop an iPhone App.  I am using a web request to call a service that returns a cookie.  My main aim is to be able to use the cookie as needed for web requests in various view controllers.  I am assuming using the Shared Storage for the cookie is the way to go.

I have had a go at this and found the following hurdles:

- The HttpWebResponse has a cookie collection made up of System.Net.Cookie objects.
- The NSSharedStorage object only takes NSHttpCookie objects.

I haven't been able to figure out a way to turn a System.Net.Cookie object into an NSHttpCookie object.  This is mainly because NSHttpCookie has only readonly properties and I am not sure how to create one using the constructors/static functions in C#.

So I really have two questions:

1. Is inserting the cookie into shared storage the best way to achieve my aim?
2. If so, how do I do this?

UPDATE:

Just to clarify a little further.  The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097757/how-do-i-convert-an-nshttpcookie-to-a-system-net-cookie-in-monotouch) is doing the opposite of what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's such thing as a NSSharedStorage. Is [NSHTTPCookieStorage](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003665) what you mean? If so, this wouldn't work for you. As per the documentation: "Cookies are not shared among applications in iOS". There also isn't a quick way to do what you want. You'll have to do something like what is suggested in the link you provided in your update. i.e. create an extension method (or some kind of utility method) that does the conversion.

You will likely have to manage your own collection of System.Net.Cookies in your app.

Comment: Yeah I was talking about NSHttpCookieStorage and I was aware that cookies are not shared between apps.  It was my understanding (perhaps incorrect) that the NSHttpCookieStorage object was the standard place to store cookies and that's why I was looking for a solution that accommodate that.

Comment: continued... As stated I mainly wanted somewhere to stick the cookie so it could be reused as required.  Creating an extension method going from System.Net.Cookie to NSHttpCookie is not as simple as shown in the question I linked because the properties on NSHttpCookie are all readonly and it's not clear (at least to me) how I am supposed to set the properties using the provided constructors.  Anyway I have created a property in my Application and I am using that to store the cookie.  This solves my problem.

Comment: Good that you found a solution. For future though, if you ever wanted to create an NSHttpCookie, you'll have to use the static factory method `CookieFromProperties()` passing in a NSDictionary of properties. See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookie_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001702-DontLinkElementID_2) for the valid keys you can use in the NSDictionary.